# Creating a Last Activity timestamp for displaying number of current users logged in on any page

Tags: php, html, database, prepared-statement

My dilemma:

1. Creating a Last Activity timestamp column in users table...
2. Creating the necessary info needed to update and select lastactivity for each logged in user and display that info in numbers for each page in PHP and html...

With that being said, I'd like the numbers to reflect only those who are currently logged into the site.  If a user logs out, the number decreases and any user who logs in the number increases of course.  All based on perhaps a 5-10 minute interval.

Am I on the right track, and if not, could someone help point me in the right direction of what I need or do not need?

What I have atm:

what is in my users table:

```
lastactivity | timestamp | Default being CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

What I currently have via users class in PHP:

```
public function update_user($clan_tag,
                    $gamer_tag,
                    $gender,
                    $day,
                    $month,
                    $year,
                    $location,
                    $occupation,
                    $interests,
                    $bio,
                    $status,
                    $xfire,
                    $steam,
                    $image_location,
                    $lastactivity,
                    $id) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET
                                `clan_tag`      = ?,
                                `gamer_tag`     = ?,
                                `gender`        = ?,
                                `day`           = ?,
                                `month`         = ?,
                                `year`          = ?,
                                `location`      = ?,
                                `occupation`        = ?,
                                `interests`     = ?,
                                `bio`           = ?,
                                `status`        = ?,
                                `xfire`         = ?,
                                `steam`         = ?,
                                `image_location`    = ?,
                                `lastactivity` = ?

                                WHERE `id`      = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $clan_tag);
        $query->bindValue(2, $gamer_tag);
        $query->bindValue(3, $gender);
        $query->bindValue(4, $day);
        $query->bindValue(5, $month);
        $query->bindValue(6, $year);
        $query->bindValue(7, $location);
        $query->bindValue(8, $occupation);
        $query->bindValue(9, $interests);
        $query->bindValue(10, $bio);
        $query->bindValue(11, $status);
        $query->bindValue(12, $xfire);
        $query->bindValue(13, $steam);
        $query->bindValue(14, $image_location);
        $query->bindValue(15, $lastactivity);
        $query->bindValue(16, $id);

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

public function update_lastactivity($lastactivity, $id){

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` where `lastactivity` >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()-(60*20))");

        $query->bindValue(1, $lastactivity);
        $query->bindValue(2, $id);

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

What I would like to use on each page:

```
<p><?php echo $lastactivity; ?> users online</p>
```

Comment: Anybody have an answer or solution or any advice?